# Angular Firebase service worker deploy in folder

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I use Firebase to send  push notifications to my Angular app.

I do it following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@a.adendrata/push-notifications-with-angular-6-firebase-cloud-massaging-dbfb5fbc0eeb

and all works ok when I try it in localhost.

The problem is when I deploy it because I do it in a folder, but the service worker is still search in the root and then is not found.

I deploy with this command:

ng build --prod --base-href /myfolder/

And then the service worker is in:

https://mydomian.com/myfolder/firebase-messaging-sw.js

But the app still search for it in

https://mydomian.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js

How can I say search it in myfolder?

I see some similar question here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es-419#!searchin/firebase-talk/firebase$20deploy$20in$20folder|sort:date/firebase-talk/1QKGP1lYj_A/k9hjXolECAAJ

But I don't have this firebase.json... I suppouse is because is an Angular app.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u found any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Created temporary script. (replacefile.js)

while building angular prod file:

> ng build --prod && node ./replacefile.js

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const options = {
  files: 'dist/enlink/*.js',
  from: "register(\"/firebase-messaging-sw.js\",{scope:\"/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope\"})",
  to: "register(\"firebase-messaging-sw.js\",{scope:\"firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope\"})",
  allowEmptyPaths: false,
};

try {
  replace.sync(options);
  console.log('Firebase service worker path fixed!');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error occurred:', error);
}
```

replacing path '/' -> '' will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and I solve it by, after build the aplication, in one of the files with a name similar to '4.a514e2ef0845553d68e7.js' search this code

> navigator.serviceWorker.register ("/ firebase-messaging-sw.js",
>   {scope: "/ firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope"})

with absolute path

And change for

> navigator.serviceWorker.register ("firebase-messaging-sw.js", {scope:
>   "firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope"})

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juan Medina, it's works.... but I hope someone can told how we can deploy it without have change by hand?

Comment: any solution without changing absolute path ?